# Is it possible to bind an application to a specific WAN port using a DI-LB604 dual wan Router

Tags: router, port, wan, bindings

What I'm trying to do is bind applications to specific WAN ports to maximize internet usage and prevent applications from getting all the bandwidth as well as categorizing which ISP they should be using, I am currently using a **DI-LB604 Dual-Wan Load Balancing router** that *has 2 Internet ISP provider currently connected to it*, an example of what i would want to achieve is:

**WAN 1 :** Google Chrome,  IE, Opera, Yahoo Messenger, Bria Professional 3.0

**WAN 2 :**  Skype, Firefox, X-Lite, FileZilla, Insta Messenger

All of the applications will only use the specific ports they are strictly binded to and in no situation use another WAN port, so if the  internet connection from WAN 1  goes out
all applications that are binded to that port will not be able to access the internet
or switch to WAN 2 and vice versa.

**here is the emulator for the router:**

http://www.support.dlink.com/emulators/dilb604/wizard.htm